# If $-A \le B\le A$, can be say that the support $s(B)$ of $B$ is smaller than $s(A)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

For a positive bounded linear operaotr $A$ and a self-adjoint bounded linear operator $B$ on a Hilbert space $H$ with $-A \le B\le A$, can be say that the support  $s(B)$ of $B$ is smaller than $s(A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1.** $B\geq 0$.

Since $ 0\leq \langle Bh,h\rangle\leq \langle Ah,h\rangle$, $ \langle Bh,h\rangle=0$ on $\ker A$,i.e., $B^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$ on $\ker A$.
Hence, $\ker A\subset \ker B^{\frac{1}{2}}\subset \ker B$.

**Case 2.**

Since $0\leq A+B\leq 2A$,  we have $\ker 2A\subset \ker (A+B)$ by Case 1,  which is equivalent to $\ker A\subset \ker B$.

Comment: why can you say $\langle Bh, h\rangle$ implies  that $B=0$ on the ker of $A$?

Comment: @user92646 By *Polarization Identity* $\langle Bh,k\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^{3} i^n\langle B(h+i^n k), h+i^n k\rangle$, $\langle Bh, h\rangle =0$ on a Hilbert space implies $\langle Bh, k\rangle =0$.

Comment: you only have $\langle Bh, h \rangle =0$ for $h\in Ker A$ not $h\in H$, the whole Hilbert space

Comment: Hi, I think you only show that B is 0 on the subHilbert space. It doesn't mean (Bh, k)＝0 for every k in the Hilbert space.

Comment: @user92646 You are right, I made a mistake. $B=0$ on $\ker A$ is not for the Polarization Identity, but for $B^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$ on $\ker A$ and $\ker B\subset\ker B^{\frac{1}{2}}$. My answer has been updated.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  $B$ is self-adjoint, how can you take $B^{1/2}$?

Comment: @user92646 Thanks to point out that, I just take $B$ as a positive element. But it still works, see the updates.

Comment: That is correct now! Beautiful! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I found a weaker version. There must be some easier proof.

Let $A,B$ be finite-rank operators.
If $-A\le B\le A$, then $ -s(B)As(B)\le B \le s(B)As(B) $. I can show that $ s(s(B)A s(B)) =s(B)$. Since $ s(s(B)A s(B)) \le s(B)$ is of course true, it suffice to prove $ s(s(B)A s(B)) \ge s(B)$.

For any  $\varepsilon >0$, $s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon$ is vertible. Then, 
$$- s(B)As(B)-\varepsilon \le  -s(B)As(B)\le B \le s(B)As(B) \le s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon . $$
Hence, $$-1 \le   (s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon)^{-1/2} B (s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon)^{-1/2} \le 1 . $$
By theorem 1.18 in [Hiai](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/bcp/bcp38/bcp3818.pdf), we obtain that for every $t>0$, 
$$\int_0^t \log \mu(t;B)dt  \le \int_0^t \log ((s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon)^{1/2} 
 (s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon)^{-1/2} B (s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon)^{-1/2}   (s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon)^{1/2} \le \int_0^t \log \mu(t;s(B)As(B)+\varepsilon).$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary and the measure of $\{\mu(s(B)As(B))\ne 0\}$ is the standard trace of $s(s(B)As(B))$, it follows that  $ s(s(B)A s(B)) \ge s(B)$.